# Список с элементами произвольных типов С++

Tags: c++, списки

В какую сторону стоит копать, чтобы создать такой список, что каждый его элемент может быть любого типа?

Пример
int -> string -> my_type

Читал про шаблоны, но даже так при создании каждого элемента приходится явно указывать тип. И тогда указатель на элемент, содержащего (допустим) string нельзя присвоить полю next элементу, содержащему int. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю.
Желательно без (или с минимальным количеством) void поинтеров

Благодарю за помощь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559412/how-to-store-different-data-types-in-one-list-c

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте список из объектов `std::any`. Накладные расходы на такие объекты относительно велики, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь.

Не ясно однако, почему вы поставили на свой вопрос метку "полиморфизм". Полиморфизм обычно подразумевает абстракцию на основе общности некоторого набора свойств. Вы же как-будто ведете речь о совершенно произвольной сборной солянке типов.